# Spectrum of a ring of continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> The set $A=\{f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f$ is continuous$\}$ is a ring with the standard function addition and multiplication. Which are the prime ideals in $A$?

The only thing I've managed to observe is that the units of this ring are the functions that never take the value $0$, so every element of a prime ideal $P$ takes the value $0$ at least once.

Comment: did you figure out which are the ideals in that ring?

Comment: I suspects the ideals are of the form $\{f \in A: f(x)=0 \forall x \in S\}$, where $S$ is a subset of $[0,1]$

Comment: The maximal ideals are well-known. But what about the prime ideals? good question.

Answer (score 1):

fix $x_0$ ,then ideal $I_0=\{f\in A: f(x_0)=0\}$ is prime. For that if $fg\in I_0$ Then either $f$ or $g$ must be zero at $x_0$.

Edit1:i dont know if these are all ...

Edit 2:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35793/prime-ideals-in-c0-1

Comment: I can see those are prime ideals.. but, why are they all the prime ideals?

Comment: You get that every element $f$ of a proper ideal $I$ satisfies $f(x)=0$ for some $x$, but that $x$ need not be the same for every $f \in I$, or does it?

Comment: Those are all *maximal* ideals.

Comment: And so prime ideals.but apparently there are examples of prime ideals of C(I) that arent maximal.